# How do I make increment the size of selected text in an EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my app (a poet/quote writing app), the user should be able to select a part of the text and either make it bigger (+7.f) or smaller (-7.f) each time an increment/decrement button is pressed.

I have been trying to adapt the code below (which **bolds** the currently selected text) to increase/decrease text size by using `AbsoluteSizeSpan`:

```
case R.id.bold:
    styleSpans = str.getSpans(selectionStart, selectionEnd, StyleSpan.class);

    // If the selected text-part already has BOLD style on it, then
    // we need to disable it
    for (int i = 0; i < styleSpans.length; i++) {
        if (styleSpans[i].getStyle() == android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD) {
            str.removeSpan(styleSpans[i]);
            exists = true;
        }
    }

    // Else we set BOLD style on it
    if (!exists) {
        str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), selectionStart, selectionEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    }

    editText.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
    break;
```

Here's my attempted adaptation for inline size changes:

```
case R.id.incline:
    android.text.style.AbsoluteSizeSpan [] inclineSpan = str.getSpans(selectionStart, selectionEnd,   android.text.style.AbsoluteSizeSpan.class);

    str.setSpan(new android.text.style.AbsoluteSizeSpan(editText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT  _PX, editText.getTextSize() + 7.f)), selectionStart, selectionEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    editText.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
    break;
```

However, this code only increases the selected text size the *first* time the increment button is pressed, whereas I want the selected text size to increase *every* time the increment button is pressed. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally worked out a solution that does exactly what I want and with only two lines of code:

```
case R.id.incline:
    str.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.1f), selectionStart, selectionEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    editText.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
    break;
```

The important change was to apply a span of type `RelativeSizeSpan(1.1f)` rather than a span of type `AbsoluteSizeSpan`. Whereas `AbsoluteSizeSpan` alters text size based on the *original* text size in the `EditText`,  `RelativeSizeSpan` alters text size based on the *current* size of each character included in the span!

Comment: @stkent Thanks for that!

Comment: It doesn't subtract

Answer (score 1):

You are using getTextSize to increase the font size, but AbsoluteSizeSpan will not change the textSize, only the size of the text inside the span. You will need an auxiliar variable to control the text size, something like this:

```
//this should go in the initialization of your view
float spanTextSize = editText.getTextSize();
```

And here your case updated:

```
case R.id.incline:
            spanTextSize += 7.f;
            android.text.style.AbsoluteSizeSpan [] inclineSpan =   str.getSpans(selectionStart, selectionEnd,   android.text.style.AbsoluteSizeSpan.class);

            str.setSpan(new android.text.style.AbsoluteSizeSpan(editText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT  _PX, spanTextSize)), selectionStart, selectionEnd,   Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
            editText.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
            break;
```

Comment: This sounds right, but I'm getting an error: _"Cannot resolve constructor AbsoluteSizeSpan(void)"_ for `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX`

or look at this srceenshot: [link](http://oi63.tinypic.com/154zw4o.jpg)

Comment: @Elshaw yeah, it is strange to pass the return of setTextSize to a constructor, since setTextSize returns void. I didn't tested your code, I only made the changes here are SO. Also, your link is broken.

Comment: I dont know what else to do. If I do this:  `str.setSpan(new android.text.style.AbsoluteSizeSpan((int) spanTextSize), selectionStart, selectionEnd,  Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);`

the selected text will increase in size just one time and not again if you press on the button.

Maybee we should use something else instead of AbsoluteSizeSpan

Comment: @Elshaw are you increasing the spanTextSize each time?

Comment: Thats what should happend everytime I click on the increase button. So its should increase 7f for every click. I hope you understand me

Comment: @Elshaw yes, I understood you, but are you sure that you are incrementing the variable spanTextSize. Put some log to see his content.

Comment: Hi I'm back again and I have tried what you suggested. The log shows that the variable spanTextSize is 61.0 for every time I press on the button to increase the size. So its not changing

Comment: Nevermind!! I have finally solved the problem and posted the solution below! take a look at it